# Set spreadsheet cell formatting using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

When editing spreadsheet we can specify cell formatting using this button:

[image]

I would like to do same thing using Apps Script, but I cannot find that in API. There is a method called `copyFormatToRange` but it's not exactly what I need.

Is there a way to set somehow formatting of cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

> sheet.getRange(5, 3).setNumberFormat("0.0");

for fixed decimals and

> sheet.getRange('A1').setNumberFormat("$0.00");

for values in Dollars.

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, it works. I haven't thought that this method may be used for that. Thanks!